# algebra, equivalence relation regarding associates

Tags: relations

If f(x) ~ g(x) if and only if f and g are associates,
prove this is an equivalence relation

have tried to prove this both ways, struggling

Comment: what do you mean associates? should we assume these are elements of a polynomial ring and this means that there is a unit such that ..?

Comment: associates meaning: if f(x),g(x) exist in some F[x], and f(x)=u*g(x). f(x) is an associate of g(x) and u^(-1)*f(x)=g(x). then f(x) and g(x) are associates

Comment: @ElizaK Please [edit] your question to include this important information. We can't read your mind after all :). Thanks in advance.

Comment: So sorry, still new at this. This is all information the professor provided, what other information should i provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to show 3 things :

1. Reflexivity : Take $u=1$
2. Symmetry : If $u$ works in one direction, then $u^{-1}$ works in the other.
3. Transitivity : If $f(x) = ug(x)$ and $g(x) = vh(x)$, then $f(x) = (uv)h(x)$, and $uv$ is a unit if $u$ and $v$ are.

Comment: makes sense, thank you!